# XSLT to create XML tag with counter inside the tag

Tags: xml, xslt

Thank you for the response.

Sorry for being not clear about the question.

I created XSLT as below.

`

```
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/"> 
      <DataElementsList>
      <xsl:for-each select="//BC4JDataElementTransferObject">
       <xsl:variable name="index" select="count(preceding-sibling::BC4JDataElementTransferObject)+1" />
         <DataElement>
             <PUBLICID>
              <xsl:value-of select="//BC4JDataElementTransferObject[$index]/@public-id"/>
          </PUBLICID>
            <LONGNAME>
              <xsl:value-of select="//BC4JDataElementTransferObject[$index]/long-name"/>
          </LONGNAME>  
         </DataElement>  
      </xsl:for-each>                                                                
    </DataElementsList>
 </xsl:template>
```

`

So far, I have output as an XML file as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<DataElementsList>
   <DataElement>
      <PUBLICID>2183222</PUBLICID>
      <LONGNAME>Alpha DVG Blood Pressure, Diastolic</LONGNAME>
   </DataElement>
   <DataElement>
     <PUBLICID>7777777</PUBLICID>
     <LONGNAME>Alpha DVG Blood Pressure, Diastolic</LONGNAME>
   </DataElement>
</DataElementsList>
```

I want to make the repeatable tag to have counter. Please see sample below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<DataElementsList>
   <DataElement num="1">
      <PUBLICID>2183222</PUBLICID>
      <LONGNAME>Alpha DVG Blood Pressure, Diastolic</LONGNAME>
   </DataElement>
   <DataElement num="2">
     <PUBLICID>7777777</PUBLICID>
     <LONGNAME>Alpha DVG Blood Pressure, Diastolic</LONGNAME>
   </DataElement>
</DataElementsList>
```

From my XSLT, How can I create "Data Element" tag in which, when I run transformation my output XML will have counter inside the tag ?

Comment: <DataElement num="1">
…
…
<DataElement>
 
<DataElement num="2">
…
…
<DataElement>

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing what your XML looks like I'm going to make some assumptions on that part. However, the basic idea will still work. That being that all you need to do is use the `position()` to create your index.

I realize this take is a bit different than what you currently have but should be more efficient and produce better results.

So if you take this XML

```
<root>
  <BC4JDataElementTransferObject/>
  <BC4JDataElementTransferObject/>
  <BC4JDataElementTransferObject/>
  <BC4JDataElementTransferObject/>
  <BC4JDataElementTransferObject/>
</root>
```

And apply this XSL to it

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <DataElementsList>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//BC4JDataElementTransferObject"/>
    </DataElementsList>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="BC4JDataElementTransferObject">
    <xsl:variable name="index" select="position()" />
    <DataElement num="{$index}">
      Content here
    </DataElement>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You get this output

```
<DataElementsList>
  <DataElement num="1">
      Content here
    </DataElement>
  <DataElement num="2">
      Content here
    </DataElement>
  <DataElement num="3">
      Content here
    </DataElement>
  <DataElement num="4">
      Content here
    </DataElement>
  <DataElement num="5">
      Content here
    </DataElement>
</DataElementsList>
```

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thank you so much. Sorry for my unclear question. I was having hard time to add my code.

Comment: @user2654219 - Instead of `num="{$index}"`, you could just do `num="{position()}"`. This would allow you to remove the `xsl:variable` completely.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you just want to add a "num" attribute to each "DataElement" node that contains the value of your "index" variable.

If you replace this element in your XSLT:

```
<DataElement>
```

With this element:

```
<DataElement num="{$index}">
```

Then you should get the output as you provided in the example.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. As time permits please close out this question so others with a similar issue can see these solutions as successful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to `position()` that is much more flexible/capable is `xsl:number` (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#number).

Example:

```
<DataElement>
    <xsl:attribute name="num">
        <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <!--additional content...-->
</DataElement>
```